# API design and DAO pattern

Tags: api, dao

I need to make an API for an application (lets say Library Manager). Like many typical applications, it is made on top of an ORM tool which makes POJOs being persisted into dbms.
Now I have to make API so that other developers can use it as a JAR. Lets say, we want users to add books to library.
I have many questions about the best way to design it.

1) Is it a good idea to have DAO like classes for POJOs :

   `BookManager {
   create(...)
   delete(Book book);
   List<Book> getAll();
   ...
   }`

2) Exposing objects:

a) Should I expose actual application POJO's to API layer? 
These have some application logic which may not want to expose and some logic which I want to expose. For example, I want to expose book.getPages() but not book.deletePage(int pageNo)

b) Create duplicate objects specially for API layer. Only interface will be exposed.

c) Not expose Objects at all. API is used using parameters. For example

`BookManager {
    create(String name, int price);
    delete(String name);
    List<Pair<String, Integer>> getAll();
    ...
    }`

This means, single point of access with the system. If some operation is to be performed on the POJO, it will be called from BookManager. For example, ClockManager.start(String clockName). It also give flexibility like having methods like startAll() in ClockManager.

3) Finally, should BookManager contain a method for update(), or it should be present in Book itself? update means saving the configuration into the database. What makes more sense :

`Book book = bookManager.create("API Design");
    book.setPrice();
    book.update();`

Or,

`Book book = bookManager.create("API Design");
    book.setPrice();
    bookManager.update(book);`

Thanks in advance,
Aman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't help but feel that some of the questions that raise come about because your POJO contains functionality closer to something like ActiveRecord.  As an example Book containing ".GetPages()" method.  If it was a true POJO it would already have pages loaded (or a hidden reference to the DAO so they can be lazy loaded).   Similarly when you delete a page, you don't need to know about the DAO at that point.  You remove the page from the book then save the book to the BookDAO.  Also I wouldn't recommend the lazy loading approach of any POJO that you expose through your API.

To try and answer your questions exactly:

1. Something like that I think yes.
2. Obviously option (c) has the most potential to be used by all consumers.  If you're calling your API and you wish to delete a book, do you really want to get the book first to pass in, or do you just want to pass in the ID or name (which you may already have).
3. BookManager should have Update(Book book).  If you put Update on Book then you are crossing out of POJO into ActiveRecord type functionality.  Either are OK in the right situation, but a hybrid is always confusing.

Note: for (3) a full active record type would be

```
Book book = Book.Load("API Design"); book.SetPrice(45); book.Update()
```

Comment: Thanks Paul,It is not actually an library management system. I just tried to come up with some real world example.

Comment: OK, just used your example to illustrate what I meant by activerecord patten - the load is a static (C#, not sure what it is in Java) method on the object as it's purpose is to create an instance, whilst Update is method on the instance.

Comment: Thanks Paul,It is not actually an library management system. I just tried to come up with some real world example.<br> I completely agree with your point about crossing out of POJO into ActiveRecord type functionality. Can you please explain a scenario where it is right for having book.update(). I believe by having bookManager.update() I am giving clear signal to users that if you want to interact with the API, go through Manager interface.

Comment: Thanks Ferenc and Paul for your suggestions. I dont know how can I accept both as answers. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer:

1. Not necessarily. I wouldn't let the ORM tool I use dictate my design. You did not  say what tool are you using, but good ones are very flexible and can persist almost any POJO design.
2. Choose b). Do not expose more than you need, but it is better to expose objects than to introduce the kind of indirection used in c)

3) The first option is better.

I'm actually not as sure that I'm giving you the right advice as I might sound. The reason being that they are many tradeoffs to consider. This is the best advice I have based on what I know about you project...

I maintain a website about API design:

http://theamiableapi.com/

You might also want to read a book or two. Look under Resources in the menu. The one by Joshua Bloch or perhaps the one by Jaroslav Tulach

Ferenc

Comment: Thanks Ferenc, Just completed the video on API design by Joshua Bloch. Have started reading one book. ORM tool is DataNucleus.

Comment: It must be very confusing to see the two responses (so far) almost contradict each other. The funny thing is that I don't disagree with Paul below. He is giving you the right advice about typical ORM usage patterns. I've approached you problem more from a Java API design perspective, where you try to hide as much of the implementation details (in this case how the persistence layer works) as you can. Only you can tell what is more important in your case.